# Rails dropdown menu population with Ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to find hack-y ways around my ignorance, but I can see that it's just flat-out not working, so here's the problem:

I'm writing the _form.html.erb for the creation of an appointment. Each appointment is between a client and a contractor.

There's a dropdown menu for the client...

```
<%= collection_select :client_id, :id, Client.all, 
:id, :name, {}, {:onchange => CONTROLLER_CALL_GOES_HERE} %>
```

And the contractor menu starts out with just the prompt "Please select client"

Each client and contractor also has a field: "expertise" for client and "need" for contractor.

What I want is to make it so that when a client is selected from the dropdown menu, the contractor menu is dynamically updated to only include those contractors whose need field is the same as the client's expertise field.

Problem is, I'm new to Ajax/jquery and kind of muddled as to what to do now.

I know I need to send a request to the controller on :onchange, and I need that def in the controller to take as input the specialty of the client and return the matching companies with an identical need field.

Can I get a nudge in the direction of how to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you share your code on github, then I would be able to look more closely into it.

Comment: That would be great! [link](https://github.com/BenHolmesBacter/client-contract/tree/update1)